# How to fit regression model in R

Tags: r, time-series, linear-regression

I am attempting to do the following question and am stuck on part 1 where I am asked to fit the regression model and interpret the results. I was taught how to do this for a model with just B1 and linear (t-1978), but now with B2(t-1978)^2 I am confused how to do it? [image: Question]

```r
library(climate) #R package of choice for Time series module
trend= time(co2) - 1978
#Turn months to factors
M = factor(cycle(co2))
reg = lm(co2 ~  time ( co2 ) + I( time (co2)^2) + trend + M,
    na.action = NULL)
summary(reg)
```

I have tried the above and my trend is `NA` so it is clearly wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem pretty close (I was *very* confused by the `cycle(co2)`, `time(co2)` calls, which are working with `ts` objects. If I put in `trend` instead of `time(co2)` I get sensible answers ...

```r
reg = lm(co2 ~  trend + I(trend^2) + M, na.action = NULL)
```